# How to call SQL user function from another one, only if it exists on SQL Server 2022?

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

**Problem:**

SQL server 2022 nondeterministically throws

> Cannot find either column "ext" or the user-defined function or aggregate "ext.cfn_Something", or the name is ambiguous.

in a situation, where it should not attempt to invoke that function. It used to work fine in SQL 2016, problem started to appear after upgrade to 2022.

**Context:**

Let's have scalar user-defined function `ext.cfn_Something(@ID INT) RETURNS BIT`, and this function does NOT exist. It is designed to override default function only when it exists on the target server.

And then, we have the actual `dbo.cfn_Something(@ID INT) RETURNS BIT` that exists and does simple logic:

- Check if the `ext` version exist on this server. And use it if it does.
- Otherwise do some default trivial calculation.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.cfn_Something(@ID INT) RETURNS BIT AS 
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Ret BIT
  IF OBJECT_ID('ext.cfn_Something') IS NOT NULL
    SET @Ret=ext.cfn_Something(@ID)
  ELSE BEGIN
    SET @Ret=CASE WHEN @ID>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  END
  RETURN @Ret
END
```

This function is called from a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.csp_Something @SomeColumn INT
AS
SELECT ID, dbo.cfn_Something(ID) AS Value FROM Table WHERE SomeColumn=@SomeColumn
```

**Observations:**

- It seems to appear randomly.
- It seems to disappear after adding `WITH RECOMPUTE` to the stored procedure.
- It seems to disappear for a while after running the procedure from admin account.

I suspect it has something to do with caching execution plan for the procedure, or the function itself. And maybe one scenario (rebuild vs. reuse) is happier than the other.

**Questions:**

- Are you aware of functional change in 2022 around execution that could cause this?
- Would `WITH RECOMPILE` be a stable solution?
- Is there other `WITH` option available that could solve this?
- Is there a better way of solving the original problem, while `dbo` wouldn't change, and instalations are free to create any objects in `ext` schema?
- Is there a way to diagnose the execution vs. caching?

Thank you

I couldn't find similar problem online. I tried adding the `WITH RECOMPILE` that seems to work for now.

Comment: Most likely this is an inlining issue; the function is now inlined and as a result errors because the function doesn't exist. Honestly, inline functions *are* the better option and I would suggest that the *real* problem is the function doesn't exist on the environment and it should. If you created the above function with `SCHEMABINDING` you wouldn't be able to create it without the other function existing, but then you wouldn't ever need to you the above function either. TL;DR: The real problem is your design.

Comment: Strange though, cause according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver16 OBJECT_ID would prevent inlining

Comment: there are some hints you can apply OP to prevent inlining, if *that's* the issue, for example: WITH INLINE = OFF

Comment: at my previous place of business, we used another approach. There was always a dummy function that did some default action, and then some customers had own overrides that did something more concrete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an inlining issue (the new Scalar UDF Inlining feature). You can see this in action in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Afp3ROuz).

To be honest, the real answer is that you shouldn't rely on statements not being executed. SQL Server compiles full batches *before* executing them, and it's only because of deferred compilation that this ever worked in the first place.

---

- A better solution might be to *always* define the function, and have the override just rewrite the existing function.
- Alternatively, you could use synonyms. For example, create one default function, and have a synonym which can be changed to refer to a different one.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.cfn_Something_Default(@ID INT)
RETURNS BIT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN IIF(@ID > 0, CAST(1 AS bit), CAST(0 AS bit));
END;
```

```sql
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.cfn_Something FOR dbo.cfn_Something_Default;
```

And change it:

```sql
DROP SYNONYM dbo.cfn_Something;
```

```sql
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.cfn_Something FOR ext.cfn_Something;
```